# How to speed up table calculations based on columns and return the last values of the table?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given:

Table1 (fixed table, which can contain over 200 million rows)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [10.0, 10.0, 0.5, 1.0, 7.0, 1.1, 1.0],
    [10.0, 10.0, 0.5, 1.0, 8.0, 1.1, 1.0],
    [10.0, 20.0, 0.5, 1.0, 7.0, 1.1, 1.0],
    [10.0, 20.0, 0.5, 1.0, 8.0, 1.1, 1.0],
]

table1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=data,
    columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
)
```

Result

```
      a     b    c    d    e    f    g
0  10.0  10.0  0.5  1.0  7.0  1.1  1.0
1  10.0  10.0  0.5  1.0  8.0  1.1  1.0
2  10.0  20.0  0.5  1.0  7.0  1.1  1.0
3  10.0  20.0  0.5  1.0  8.0  1.1  1.0
```

calculate_table() (function that calculates a table based on the values from table1)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calculate_table(
    a: float,
    b: float,
    c: float,
    d: float,
    e: int,
    f: float,
    g: float,
    pr: float = 10000,
):

    m = np.arange(e + 1)
    so = np.arange(e)

    # calculations
    p = d * (f ** m - 1) / (f - 1)
    s = pr * (1 - ((d * (f ** m - 1) / (f - 1)) / 100))
    q = np.r_[a, b * g ** so]
    r = np.cumsum(q)
    t = q / s
    u = np.cumsum(t)
    v = r / u
    w = v * (1 + (c / 100))
    x = ((w - s) / s) * 100
    y = a * (c / 100)
    z = r * (c / 100)

    data = {
        "m": m,
        "p": p,
        "s": s,
        "x": x,
        "w": w,
        "v": v,
        "q": q,
        "r": r,
        "t": t,
        "u": u,
        "y": y,
        "z": z,
    }

    table = pd.DataFrame(
        data=data
    )

    return p[-1], x[-1], etc
```

Result of the table calculation:

```
(   m          p            s         x             w             v    q     r         t         u     y      z
0  0   0.000000  10000.00000  0.500000  10050.000000  10000.000000   10    10  0.001000  0.001000  0.05  0.050
1  1   0.500000   9950.00000  0.701403  10019.789579   9969.939880   15    25  0.001508  0.002508  0.05  0.125
2  2   1.250000   9875.00000  0.936901   9967.519012   9917.929365   30    55  0.003038  0.005546  0.05  0.275
3  3   2.375000   9762.50000  1.258945   9885.404507   9836.223390   60   115  0.006146  0.011691  0.05  0.575
4  4   4.062500   9593.75000  1.727164   9759.449799   9710.895322  120   235  0.012508  0.024200  0.05  1.175
5  5   6.593750   9340.62500  2.432283   9567.815435   9520.214364  240   475  0.025694  0.049894  0.05  2.375
6  6  10.390625   8960.93750  3.524930   9276.804262   9230.651007  480   955  0.053566  0.103460  0.05  4.775
7  7  16.085938   8391.40625  5.273190   8833.901006   8789.951250  960  1915  0.114403  0.217862  0.05  9.575, 16.0859375, 5.273189534595566)
```

This is what I want to accomplish:

For every row in table1 will a table be calculate by the function calculate_table(), but I'm looking for a lightning fast solution to return the last values of the table created by calculate_table() and add them to table1 as extra columns.

The problem now is that when using the apply function it will take a very long time (now 400000 rows in about 20 min).

```
table1["p", "x"] = dca_settings[["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]].apply(calculate_table, axis=1)
```

So is there a solution to vectorize the table calculations direct on table1?

Like:

```
table1["p"] = table1["d"] * (table1["f"] ** table1["m"] - 1) / (table1["f"] - 1)
```

Comment: You need to vectorize your computations, so that they can be performed on all values at once

Comment: @mozway; Do you mean that the funtion is not right programmed? Or do I need to look for better/other calculations on the table1? I'm trying to understand what you mean, but don't know where to start to vectorize the solution.

Comment: If arrays were passed to your current function, it would break. So you need to update that first: for instance the `np.cumsum` parts would need an axis defined over which the sum should be calculated. 

Also, you are creating a dataframe internally each time, which is probably a big time sink for you now. I'm guessing at this point, but you could speed up just by returning values and doing the table append at the end.